# Proper signature for collection postback?

Tags: list, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, http-post, strong-typing

I haven an entity with a collection, something like: Product.Parts - when I render a view for Product, I call .EditorFor(x => x.Parts), which names my fields like: Parts[0].Name.

how do I declare my controller method that receives the postback so it can recompose those field names into something useful?

I originally tried:

```
[HttpPost] public ActionResult Create(Product entity)
```

which seemed to give me an object of the right type but was all empty (properties were null). then I tried:

```
[HttpPost] public ActionResult Create(List<Product> entity)
```

but in this case entity itself is null. also, this didn't help:
[HttpPost] public ActionResult Create(IList entity)
I guess I can always do this:

```
[HttpPost] public ActionResult Create(FormCollection form)
{
    var Name = form["Product[0].Name"];
}
```

but that's eecky! help?

Answer (score 0):

your 1st attempt should have worked... maybe have a look at the posted values in firefox or chrome?

Comment: the first approach is how I've always done it, though I haven't tried a collection before and that's why I'm not sure of the syntax.  in any case, neither works.  the posted values are ok, I can see them in the FormCollection